# How to get the data inside of CSV file

Tags: vue.js, csv, axios

Good day,

I'm working on a project that have an import functionality. How can I retrieve the data inside of the csv file?. It is possible to retrieve it in front end or should I use axios.post?
Here is my code so far:

```
   <input 
   type="file" 
   id="files" 
   style="display: none;"
   accept=".csv" 
   ref="file"
   v-on:change="handleFileUpload()"
   />
   <button @click="onImport"> Import </button>
```

In my method :

```
 data: {
    file: '',
 },
 methods: {
     onImport() {
        $('#files').click();   
    },
     handleFileUpload() {
         this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
         let formData = new FormData();
         formData.append('file', this.file);
    }
```

Thank you in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) like so:

```js
async handleFileUpload() {
  this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];

  const reader = new FileReader();

  reader.readAsText(this.file);

  reader.onload = () => {
    console.log(reader.result); // contains the file content as a string
  };

  reader.onerror = () => {
    console.log(reader.error);
  };

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', this.file);
  
  // Send your file to your server and retrieve the response
  const res = await axios.post('https://example.com/upload', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  });
}
```

It [works](https://caniuse.com/?search=FileReader) on all major browsers also.

Comment: Then can I save and compare it to my exisiting Database?

Comment: @enriquetanada yeah of course this does not not prevent you from keep your `formData` and sending it to your server. I'll update the answer to show it to you.

Comment: Hi @geauser Thank you for the warmth response, I will wait for your answer

Comment: @enriquetanada I added the 'sending to the server' part. It uses https://github.com/axios/axios which have an extensive documentation so you should be ok on your own.